# Flutter nearby_connections

Tags: android, flutter, google-nearby-connections

I got this error when i try to advertise or discover on devices.However it worked well on the ring road the day before:

```
] PlatformException(Failure, 17: API: Nearby.CONNECTIONS_API is not available on this device. Connection failed with: ConnectionResult{statusCode=INTERNAL_ERROR, resolution=null, message=null}, null, null)      
IGmsServiceBroker.getService failed
    W/GmsClient(20955): java.lang.IllegalStateException
    W/GmsClient(20955):     at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:3031)
    W/GmsClient(20955):     at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:3007)
    W/GmsClient(20955):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2990)
    W/GmsClient(20955):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2932)
    W/GmsClient(20955):     at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzac.getService(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@18.1.0:9)
    W/GmsClient(20955):     at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.BaseGmsClient.getRemoteService(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@18.1.0:14)
    W/GmsClient(20955):     at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zabt.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.1.0:7)
    W/GmsClient(20955):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
    W/GmsClient(20955):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    W/GmsClient(20955):     at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
    W/GmsClient(20955):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
    W/GmsClient(20955):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
```

Please help me.

Comment: same here any solution you found?

Comment: No I've did'nt find a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem comes after recent updates in Google Play Services. I downgraded my Google Play Services and it starts working.

For downgrading:

1. Go to settings
2. Apps
3. Find Google Play Services app and select
4. Click on top right menu and select uninstall updates.

After doing this, Near By connections will work.

Comment: Thanks man but its not the perminant solution. Tell me if you find any permanent solution as well thanks